# Creating a virtual directory is only supported on the local IIS server

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis

I am trying to get a visual studio solution (written by someone else) working on my machine. When I try to open the solution, I get two error messages, shown in the picture below. I don't know very much about IIS so I am at a loss to debug these. What should I do? Or where should i start reading?

[image]

Comment: Website project or Web Application Project? Try creating the App pool and virtual directory first, then open as Website.

Comment: @IrishChieftain, i think web project--based on the top message shown in the picture above. but i don't really know. how do i create the app pool and virtual directory? i have been opening this project by opening the solution file

Comment: It's just a right-click operation in IIS to create both the app pool and the virtual directory. Then in VS, right-click project node for the properties window and make sure it's pointing at the virtual directory you just created in IIS.

Answer (score 8):

The virtual directory of the project is not set properly which is why its not loading, edit the virtual directory of the project by right clicking the project > edit project then find this line of code:

```
<iisurl>http://localhost</iisurl>
```

change or add the name of the web project after local host:

```
<iisurl>http://localhost/webname</iisurl>
```

Another solution is to make sure asp.net is registered to the IIS
go into visual studio tools> visual studio command prompt and typer aspnet_regiis -r

More info on registering asp.net here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Open the .csproj in notepad or another text exitor.

Comment: @bernie2436 - Right click on project - unload project, then it appears as unavailable - right click again and choose 'Edit <projectname>.csproj'

Answer (score 3):

Adding to user's answer since I can't add to comments.

Right-click the project and select "Unload Project".  You will then be permitted to right-click and edit the project file.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you have mapped project from TFS with a different version of visual studio.

Solution:
1. remove mappings from the local folders
2. Create new mapping and retrieve files to a different location
3. Open the solution from this new location